# Set red value of a pixel, WITHOUT set RGB

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel, bufferedimage

I am trying to set either red, green, or blue value of a BufferedImage.
After that, i will retrieve that red/green/blue value, and then I will process that value.

But my problem is when I doing this

```
Color cipherColor = new Color(cipherDecimal[offColor], cipherDecimal[offColor], cipherDecimal[offColor]);

int cipherColorInt = cipherColor.getRGB();
stegoImage.setRGB(x, y, cipherColorInt);
```

then, I'm curious about the value...so I add some codes to see the RGB value before and after i set the RGB

```
Color cipherColor = new Color(cipherDecimal[offColor], cipherDecimal[offColor], cipherDecimal[offColor]);

int cipherColorInt = cipherColor.getRGB();
stegoImage.setRGB(x, y, cipherColorInt);
int tesColor = stegoImage.getRGB(x, y);
System.out.println(cipherColorInt + "\t" + tesColor);
```

Info about stegoImage

> BufferedImage stegoImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),
>   img.getHeight(null)+h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
>
> img is just a normal image

It'll set RGB value almost right. ALMOST, because some of value changed. Here it is :

```
-------- RGB after and before----------
 before      after

-6052957    -6052957
-7303024    -7303024
-10855846   -10855846
-11053225   -11119018 --> changed
-3158065    -3158065
-2500135    -2500135
-13027015   -13092808 --> changed
-5658199    -5658199
-131587 -131587
-12500671   -12566464 --> changed
-5658199    -5658199
-16448251   -16777216 --> changed
-5526613    -5526613
-8553091    -8553091
-1579033    -1579033
-3421237    -3421237
```

Please help me :)
For now, if you know other way to set Red/Green/Value without setRGB or even BufferedImage please tell me.
Or perhaps, if you know what makes the value changed or how to fix it, then please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: What type is your stegoImage object?

Comment: oh, right sorry...it's 
BufferedImage stegoImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null)+h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

img is just a normal image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know that your image is `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`, it will have a linear grayscale color space and a byte databuffer, so you can get the databuffer, cast it to `DataBufferByte` and access the native gray byte values directly:

```
DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) stegoImage.getRater().getDataBuffer();
byte[] data = buffer.getData(); // signed gray values in linear gray space

// Access each pixel
byte signedGrayPixelValue = data[x + y * stegoImage.getWidth()]; // [-128...127]

// Alternatively
int grayPixelValue = data[x + y * stegoImage.getWidth()] & 0xff; // [0...255]
```

The problem with using `setRGB/getRGB`, is probably that these methods assume the value to be in sRGB color space, and thus not always corresponding to linear gray color space (ie., rounding errors will occur).

Comment: excuse me, what does that data variable contain?
i'm a bit miss about DataBufferByte

Comment: It's the gray pixel values. See update. If you need an RGB value, you could create one from `new Color(grayPixelValue, grayPixelValue, grayPixelValue)`, but it's kind of unnecessary.

Comment: wow, thanks for such a great explanation
this is new for me hahaha

Comment: Because you said the problem is because TYPE_BYTE_GRAY. then i also try to not use it...and it works haha